Can I answer Capture Input Dialog permanently
Synergy now supports Wayland, at least experimentally. I am running Ubuntu 24.10 with the default Gnome desktop environment & Wayland. I installed Synergy 3.2.1, and all works beautifully, auto discovery and everything. The only slight annoyance is that fairly often the dialog asking for permission to capture input (pictured below) pops up again, and again,.... Is there any way to configure the system to allow Synergy this permission permanently?
The other machine Synergy is connecting to is running Kubuntu 24.10 and the equivalent dialog in KDE has a "remember this" checkbox, and the dialog doesn't keep popping up. This is the sort of thing I am looking for under Ubuntu, but if a config file is involved that is totally fine.


That is not possible under GNOMEenter code here current version, when an application like Synergy ask for to capture global input, it will display a pop up.
You can bypass that but it can be tricky like reverting to xorg by logging out and choosing Ubuntu on Xorg, or using KDE like with Kubuntu 24.10 who have a remember checkbox, you can also ask GNOME dev for this feature.

That is about what I expected. I got a reply on Discord from Nick on the Synergy team that they are likely going to submit a PR to the upstream project to handle this. Hopefully that is accepted and handles this. After using it for a few days it doesn't pose much of a problem.
